# Combing pandas dataframe values based on other column values

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['WY','M',2014,'Seth',5],
             ['WY','M',2014,'Spencer',5],
             ['WY','M',2014,'Tyce',5],
             ['NY','M',2014,'Seth',25],
             ['MA','M',2014,'Spencer',23]],columns = ['state','sex','year','name','number'])

print df
```

How do I manipulate the data to get a dataframe like:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['M',2014,'Seth',30],
               ['M',2014,'Spencer',28],
               ['M',2014,'Tyce',5]],
columns = ['sex','year','name','number'])

print df1
```

This is just part of a very large dataframe, how would I do this for every name for every year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df[['sex','year','name','number']].groupby(['sex','year','name']).sum().reset_index()
```

For a brief description of what this does, from left to right:

1. Select only the columns we care about.  We could replace this part with `df.drop('state',axis=1)`
2. Perform a groupby on the columns we care about.
3. Sum the remaining columns (in this case, just `number`).
4. Reset the index so that the columns `['sex','year','name']` are no longer a part of the index.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pivot table

```
df.pivot_table(values = 'number',aggfunc = 'sum',columns = ['sex','year','name']).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'number'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by the columns you want, sum `number`, and flatten the multi-index:

```
df.groupby(['sex','year','name'])['number'].sum().reset_index()
```

In your case the column `state` is not sum-able, so you can shorten to:

```
df.groupby(['sex','year','name']).sum().reset_index()
```